# Passing Data from Broadcast Receiver to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hi I've been having an issue with Broadcast Receivers and passing information to another activity. I'm trying to create an application that will capture incoming SMS messages, look for a website in the text, then pop up an Alert Dialog box asking if the user wants to go to the website.

```
public class TextReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // .. other code that
    // sets received SMS into message

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
            "Received Text: " + message.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
 }
```

So that code works fine, receive a text it pops up a toast with the message. The toast is useless but it shows the receiver works. But I want to communicate with an activity to show an Alert Dialog and start up a webView. I already programmed the code that will take a string search for the website and open the webView. Is it possible to get the string from the broadcast receiver and do something like this?:

```
    public class ReceiveText extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Somehow pass the string from the receiver into this activity, 
//stored in variable messages

findOpen(messages);

// is that possible?

}
public class findOpen(string messages){
// do stuff ... open alert...open site if OK
}
```

So basically I just want to pass a string from a Broadcast Receiver to another activity that will use that string. The rest of the code is basically in place all I need is that string... I'm new to this and Java and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have your activity named `ReceiveText`, then in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you should do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceiveText.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("message", message.getMessageBody());
context.startActivity(i);
```

Then, in your activity, you will need to getExtra as so:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

And then you will use `message` as you need.

If you simply want the `ReceiveText` activity to show the message as a dialog, declare `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />` in your manifest for `ReceiveText` and then set the message to a textview in the activity.

**EDIT:** This restarts your activity. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22288087/802469) is likely a better solution for most people.

Comment: For anyone going forward with this implementation, it'll restart your activity. Probably something you don't want.

Answer (score 18):

1. Instantiate a BroadcastReceiver in the activity you want to get your data to, for example:

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver mServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           //Extract your data - better to use constants...
           String IncomingSms=intent.getStringExtra("incomingSms");//
           String phoneNumber=intent.getStringExtra("incomingPhoneNumber");

       }
   };
   ```
2. Unregister your receiver on `onPause()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       try {
           if(mServiceReceiver != null){
           unregisterReceiver(mServiceReceiver);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register it on `onResume()`:

   ```
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver");
       registerReceiver(mServiceReceiver , filter);
   }
   ```
4. Broadcast your data from the service via an Intent, for Example:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver").putExtra("incomingSms", message);
   i.putExtra("incomingPhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
   context.sendBroadcast(i);
   ```

and that's it! goodLuck!

Comment: @Dinesh Yes. the code is missing IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

Comment: Much better than the answer above in my opinion because you don't have to reload the activity.

Comment: Excellent answer. This deserves to be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can send the data from onReceive to another activity using LocalBroadcastManager.
It means you are again broadcasting the data using the context

```java
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
        Log.d("Broadcast", "wifi  ConnectivityReceiver");
    
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                Intent intent = new Intent("broadCastName");
                // Data you need to pass to another activity
                intent .putExtra("message", extras.getString(Config.MESSAGE_KEY)); 
                context.sendBroadcast(intent );
    }
```