# How to transfer data from one activity to another in android studio without opening the new activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, mobile-development

I am trying to create a recycler view with data from another activity. I need to transfer data from one activity to the recycler view activity without it opening the recycler view activity. Because only when I press another button do I want to go to the next activity.

I have tried using intent, however `startActivity(intent)` always opens the other activity. I also tried using Share preferences to save the data and retrieve it in the other activity. However, `Base64.DEFAULT` was not working for me.

```java
public void sendData(Bitmap images, String image_class) {
    Intent send = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scanned_List_Activity.class);
    send.putExtra("image_class",image_class);
    send.putExtra("image", images);
    startActivity(send);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you were achieving can you explain in detail.

Comment: You can not [have two activities alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102337/can-you-have-two-activities-running-at-the-same-time) at the same time. You can replace that with fragments

Comment: You can use Broadcast receiver to send data to another activity without calling it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137477/passing-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you should do it differently.

Activity represents a `View` or better to say a `Controller` in the `MVC` architecture. Data you gained in the `RecyclerReceiver` comes from a model, activity just passes it to a view. That's why the right way is to have this data in the model layer rather than pass it over an `Intent` as a `Parcelable` object.

Nowadays we have a `ViewModel` class which is a layer between a `model` and your `view`. If you use DI tool like dagger you can keep a single instance of your `ViewModel` between this two activities - when you prepare your dataset on the first activity, the second activity will get it next time when it would be opened.

In short you should put this dataset either in the separate table and request from 2nd activity or to put on the `ViewModel` which single instance is shared between this two activities.

[image]